# JAVA: There are no Errors in my code, But i'm not getting the right answer

Tags: java

Here's the part of the code that could contain a problem. This is my class.

```
private int GCD(int Num, int Denom)
    {
        int gcd;
        gcd = Num % Denom;
        if(gcd == 0)
            return Denom;
        else
        {
            return GCD(Denom, gcd);
        }
    }

    public Fractions add(Fractions frac)
    {
        Fractions newFrac = new Fractions();
        this.Num = this.Num * frac.Denom;
        this.Denom = this.Denom * frac.Denom;
        frac.Num = frac.Num * this.Denom;
        frac.Denom = frac.Denom * this.Denom;
        frac.Denom = this.Denom;
        newFrac.Denom = frac.Denom;
        newFrac.Num = this.Num + frac.Num;
        Denom = GCD(newFrac.Num, newFrac.Denom);
        if (Denom == 0)
            return newFrac;
        else
        {
            newFrac.Num = newFrac.Num / Denom;
            newFrac.Denom = newFrac.Denom / Denom;
            return newFrac;
        }
    }
```

Here's the small demo code I wrote for it. Please help me find the problem.

```
public class FractionsDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Fractions frac1 = new Fractions();
        Fractions frac2 = new Fractions();
        Fractions frac3 = new Fractions();

        frac1.read();
        frac2.read();

        System.out.println("The first fraction is " + frac1.Num + "/" + frac1.Denom);
        System.out.println("The second fraction is " + frac2.Num +"/" + frac2.Denom);


        frac3 = frac1.add(frac2);
        System.out.println("adding the first and second results in " + frac3.Num + "/" + frac3.Denom );



    }

}
```

As I mentioned in the title, my code doesn't display any errors. The problem is a logic problem. Your help would be much appreciated. Also, please try to explain the reason for your solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `"JAVA: There are no Errors in my code, But i'm not getting the right answer"` -- Then there must be an error in your code. Seriously. You are grossly confusing compilation errors with logic errors. Your code may have none of the former, but it surely has at least one if not more of the latter, and for this you need to use a debugger.

Comment: How do you define *error*? Did you check [Relay #70, Panel F](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~jamie/C/Debug/LectureNotes/moth.html)?

Comment: I mean it's a logic error. I get a wrong answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ... or misapprehension regarding the right answer

Comment: What result are you getting and what did you expect to get?

Comment: In all seriousness, titles like that are down-vote magnets. If you want to attract better help, correct it.

Comment: And debug your code to figure out what's wrong.  If you have a specific question about how something works, ask it.  But don't complain that "it doesn't work right' and expect us to fix it for you.

Comment: I tried to add 6/3 and 3/6 and got 5/1. i was supposed to get 5/2

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: You appear to have a integer division issue `newFrac.Num = newFrac.Num / Denom`...?

Comment: @HotLicks i don't expect you to fix it for me. I'm new at java and therefore make mistakes that look stupid to you. So, I was just asking for help, not for you to do my work for me.

Comment: @jiija, you should realise that the _instant_ you resorted to name-calling, a large section of your solution space disappeared (http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much. That was the problem

Comment: how is that an integer division issue? GCD is, well the GCD of both Num and Denom. By definition dividing a integer by its greatest common divisor will always yield an integer. That part looks right to me. How did that fix your problem? Did you see my answer below?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is here

```
    this.Denom = this.Denom * frac.Denom;
    frac.Num = frac.Num * this.Denom;
```

Your setting this.Denom before you set frac.Num, you have to switch the order to

```
    frac.Num = frac.Num * this.Denom;
    this.Denom = this.Denom * frac.Denom;
```